# Another apparent time dilation paradox in special relativity that questions the symmetricness of time dilation

Tags: special-relativity

Let's have the classical setup of a stationary observer A and moving observer B moving in the direction of A starting from somewhere far-away.  Let's assume the world is three dimensional and, WLOG, B is moving along the x-axis.

Let's have A setup a pendulum that swings in the y-z plane.  It is swinging with initial condition and angular velocity such that by the time B reaches A, the pendulum would be in position to block B (collide) and destroy B.
Because the movement of pendulum is orthogonal to x-axis, there would be no length contraction.

There is a paradox:
From the perspective of B, A's time is drastically slowed down compared to local time, so that when B reaches A (or A reaches B from B's perspective), B's pendulum would not be in a position to intercept A.  However, from A's perspective, it is.

So is there a collision or not?

Comment: Are you forgetting the relativity of simultaneity?  In particular, the events that (1) B is located at $x_0$, and (2) that the pendulum begins it downward swing are simultaneous according to A but are *not* simultaneous according to B.

Comment: Why wouldn't the pendulum be in a position to intercept A?  Surely that position is possible regardless of the (perceived) speed of oscillation?  Without more information about the starting position, I don't see any paradox.

Comment: I think that in your next to last sentence you accidentally switched A and B.  But no matter:  the pendulum hits B, and as @BowlOfRed says, there's no need for A and B to agree on its speed, so there's not even an **apparent** paradox.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be based on a complete non sequitur.

Answer (score 1):

> So is there a collision or not?

There is a collision, and both frames agree that there will be a collision.

As is almost always the case, the problem with the analysis in the question stems from neglecting the relativity of simultaneity.

Suppose that the pendulum is at the peak of the swing at time t=0. In A’s frame that corresponds to some point on B’s worldline where (according to A) B has 1/4 of a “tick-tock” until impact. However in B’s frame that same event is simultaneous with the pendulum already being partway through the swing. So although the pendulum is time dilated, it still collides because it has just enough of a head start.

In general, the vast majority of SR “paradoxes” are a direct result of neglecting the relativity of simultaneity.